# Add script inheriting from scriptableobject to game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, scripting

I have a script called Weapon.cs, which is a scriptable object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Weapon : ScriptableObject {

protected Camera _mainCamera;
protected Transform _weaponTransform;
protected int _damage;
protected int _fireRatePerSecond;
protected bool _isAutomaticWeapon;

protected void FireWeapon()
{
    //if the weapon is automatic
    if (_isAutomaticWeapon)
    {
        ShootRapidFireOnMouseHold();
    }
    //if the weapon is semi automatic
    else
    {
        ShootSingleBulletOnMouseClick();
    }
}

protected void MoveWeaponWithCamera(Transform weaponTransform)
{
    _weaponTransform.rotation = _mainCamera.transform.rotation; //temporary way of making sure the gun moves with the camera
}

protected void ShootSingleBulletOnMouseClick()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)) //if left mouse button is clicked
    {
        CastRay();
    }
}

protected void ShootRapidFireOnMouseHold()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) //if left mouse button is held down
    {
        CastRay(); //rapid fire
        //PlayShootAnimation();
    }
}

protected void CastRay()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(_mainCamera.transform.position, _mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, 100))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
    }
}
//protected abstract void PlayShootAnimation();
}
```

I have a second script called MachineGun.cs, which inherits from Weapon.cs, and thus indirectly from scriptable object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MachineGun : Weapon{

private GameObject _machineGunBarrel;

//private float _animationVelocity;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //initialize the basic properties of a weapon
    _damage = 7;
    _fireRatePerSecond = 10;
    _isAutomaticWeapon = true;

    _weaponTransform = GameObject.Find("Weapon_MachineGun").transform;
    _machineGunBarrel = GameObject.Find("machinegun_p1");

    _mainCamera = Camera.main;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    MoveWeaponWithCamera(_weaponTransform);
    FireWeapon();
}

//protected override void Shoot()
//{
//    RaycastHit hit;
//    if(Physics.Raycast(_mainCamera.transform.position, _mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, 100))
//    {
//        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
//    }
//}

void PlayShootAnimation()
{
    _machineGunBarrel.transform.RotateAround(_machineGunBarrel.transform.up, _fireRatePerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
    PlayShootAnimation(); //play the shoot animation of the gun
}
}
```

It's currently impossible, since MachineGun.cs doesn't inherit from monobehaviour anymore.

I have a weapon gameobject in my scene, and so here's my question:
How do I go about adding the MachineGun.cs script as a component to my weapon gameobject? Or since this is impossible,

**How should I build a weapon system with a general Weapon.cs script from which all weapons can inherit basic functions and fields/variables?**

EDIT 1: provided code to my post and added the "why I wanna do this".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If a script does not inherit from `Component` (or `MonoBehaviour`), there is **no way** to add it as a component of a GameObject. ScriptableObjects are meant to be **assets** in your project (holding data in _most_ of the cases). Then, you can use them in **other scripts** inheriting from MonoBehaviour, attached to GameObjects.

Comment: I've edited my post to make my intentions clear.

Comment: I do you need to make `Weapon` inherit from `ScriptableObject`? You don't use the [`CreateAssetMenu`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html) attribute.... So I guess you don't create a real ScriptableObject in your project tab? (unless you have the appropriate Editor script to do so)

Comment: I thought it was a good way to get the same behaviour from a ScriptableObject as from a public abstract Weapon class, with the added benefit of inherited fields..

Comment: Just make `Weapon` inherit from `MonoBehaviour` and all your problems will fade away. `Weapon` can be `abstract` and you can keep the inherited fields.

Comment: Isn't the problem then that when I assign a value to the fields from the Weapon class in the MachineGun class, that the value in the fields change for all weapons?

Comment: Once the script is attached to a GameObject, a new instance is created, and the values you provide in the editor (or by script, at runtime), won't affect the other instances (except if you use `static` class variables)

Comment: That's great, didn't know I could have just done it this way all along.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ScriptableObjects** should mainly be used in a data oriented way, they are very convenient and quite efficient for the task. Also, plaguing your project of **MonoBehaviour** is a very bad (and wide-spread) practice.

**IMO**, you should have a **MonoBehaviour** with weapon logic management and your **ScriptableObjects** should be your weapon data (which is interpreted by loading them up in your Weapon **MonoBehaviour**), such that you have Minigun, Glock, Katana.. **Scriptable objects** which have data like, attack speed, reload speed, charger size, weapon model/textures, reference to model hitbox, yadayadayada. (You might have a generic Weapon **MonoBehaviour**, but derive a Gun one, a Blade etc.. for very specific management, but which will still need data from **ScriptableObjects**)

In short your **MonoBehaviours** define usage and interaction, while your **ScriptableObjects** define characteristics

Comment: Could you give a code sample of this?
Since I'm not sure I completely understand what you're saying.
So I should create a ScriptableObject which contains all the fields a weapon could have, and also a Weapon monobehaviour script with all methods a weapon could have?

Comment: @Thrindil I'll try and mock something up, but I stumbled here while searching, I'm currently at work so, I might not have the opportunity to post any time soon. But if this could help, ScriptableObjects have database-like characteristics, they will only contain information which can be used or transformed. You could do all this inside MonoBehaviours, a lot of people do it, but because you can, doesn't mean that you should. For a very brief explanation, think of a HP combat system, your current/max hp is your scriptableObject and Inflicting/TakingDamage is your monobehaviour.

Comment: @Thrindil A very good exemple (without code) is Virtual Card Games (ex: Hearthstone/Slay the spire etc..) Your scriptable object will have the cards : Name, Damage, max Hp/current Hp, Description and Type (and possibly a buff/debuff field or something, but what ever). Since our information is generic, we arent going to create 500 gameobjects of almost identical cards, no, we have a builder which can construct your card thanks to your SO data, there will also be a behaviour which is generic, basically just a `Use()` which will activate whatever the card can do, no more needed.

Comment: @Thrindil For a sense of what I'm trying to say, i'd advise you to look at the [Ability System lesson from Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/ability-system-scriptable-objects) as well as [Overthrowing the MonoBehaviour tyranny in a glorious ScriptableObject revolution](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/overthrowing-monobehaviour-tyranny-glorious-scriptableobject), Nothing is really absolute and there are many ways of doing of course, most of what i've put forward are for reasons of clarity, abstraction and maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification even though you're at work.
I'll read through/watch your provided documentation, and accept your answer as the right one since you've been very helpful.

Comment: @Thrindil Thanks a lot ! I'm glad I can help. You should find quite relevant answers in the Ability tutorial to your question `"How should I build a weapon system with a general Weapon.cs script from which all weapons can inherit basic functions and fields/variables?"`, The second video is more of a general purpose guide as to why build around this model. Happy coding!

Comment: @Thrindil Were you able to achieve your desired outcome ?

Comment: Yes, I ended up with a weapon system with an abstract class weapon, from which every weapon inherits.

Comment: @Thrindil Good on you ! How's the game coming together ?

Answer (score 1):

[ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) says:

> Description
>
> A class you can derive from if you want to **create objects that don't
> need to be attached to game objects**.

So either you should not attach this script to game object or derive your object from "MonoBehaviour" if you want to attach it to game object.

Why did you derive it from `ScriptableObject` ?

Comment: Weapon has behaviour like shoot, move, reload etc so it should be defined as `MonoBehaviour`. Common behaviour of any weapon you are using should be defined in Weapon class. You can also compare the use of ScriptableObject from here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects. Perhaps it will give you a better idea for the use of ScriptableObject.